# How to show jenkins user's groups?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to configure Jenkins with various permissions for different groups.  I recall pulling up a page that displayed the logged in user's group memberships but I can't find it again.  Does anyone know the URL for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> there is also another page "/whoAmI", but I think has the same
>   information which may not help
>
> - psftw (#jenkins on freenode)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, when I visit any user's page http://jenkins.mycompany.com/user/{userid}/ (e.g. from menu "people"), I get pretty much the list of groups displayed. I don't believe I'm getting this thru a specific plugin (I'm using the ActiveDirectory Plugin, and I understand that the LDAP plugin would behave pretty much the same).

So if you're also attempting to use LDAP groups, it may simply be that you haven't configured that integration correctly. If you haven't yet, I'd suggest looking at this [LDAP troubleshooting page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin#LDAPPlugin-Troubleshooting) 
Additionally, this [SO Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/286130/jenkins-hudson-ldap-group-lookup-does-not-work) might also help.